# How to get flutter local notifications data?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile, flutter-local-notification

I'm working on a mobile app using Flutter 1.17.5. I've setup 2 notifications using flutter_local_notifications and i need to get the data from the user when they click in a notification. I've been able to get the current user logged and the time the notification was selected, but i also need the time the notification was delivered to the user and whether it was opened or canceled. I was thinking maybe getting the notification by id and then working with it, but i have no idea how to do that at the moment, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using it in background? Do you need ackwonledgment? Are you using Firebase? 
You could try [awesome_notifications][1] with action button. Way better than flutter_local_notifications.

Comment: Yes im using it in background. I'm not using Firebase, is it necessary? I will take a look at awesome_notifications but at the moment we have to use flutter_local_notifications, and later we could switch to another notifications plugin. Do you know any way to do it with flutter_local_notifications?

Comment: Your data need to be send to Firebase or anything else. So use Firebastore in the background. That way you'll know everything.https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-local-notifications-and-cloud-firestore-queries-in-the-background-44a077caa5c3

Comment: when i setup firebase in the background, can you give me any ideas on how i could get these informations i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your data need to be send to Firebase or anything else. So use
> Firebastore in the background. That way you'll know
> everything. https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-local-notifications-and-cloud-firestore-queries-in-the-background-44a077caa5c3

This worked for me. thanks to [mario francois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11510697/mario-francois)